# How to add journal, volume and pages to biblatex references?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex, citing

I'm making a beamer presentation and i would like to reference in my presentation by showing the first author name, journal, volume, pages and year. Something like:

> Author et al., Journal **Volume**, starting page (year).

It would be very nice if I could get volume in bold text and only get the starting page. About the Author name it would be cool if there's only one author get only he's name, without "et al."

I couldn't found any style that do it like that.

Actually, using `style=authoryear`, author name and year is quite easy to get but i'm having troubles with journal, volume and pages.

Looking for some questions already answered here I made to use `\renewbibmacro*{cite}` and `\usbibmacro{journal}` to get Author, Journal, Year with the following code. But I still can't do in the format I want.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{journal}
        \setunit{\addcomma\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

Can someone help me getting the references in the format that I need?

Best regards

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE, please make your code compilable using the [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) template.